# horizontal scroll bar won't display on IE 8

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

**Website**: http://www.gunsamerica.com

**Problem**: IE 8 users with screen resolutions less than 1200px are NOT able to scroll horizontally to see full content. On all other browsers with screen resolutions set less than 1200px the scroll bar is visible. On IE 8 (of course) it's not allowing the horizontal scroll bar to be used.

**Failed Attempts**: I tried using CSS fixes such as overflow, overflow-x, and -ms-overflow-style. As far as I can tell none of those have made any difference. I'm wondering if the viewport settings may have something to do with it? (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1260" />`)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You set your site to Html 5, which isn't fully compliant in IE8.  Try using this doctype for ie8 (conditionally)

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Would this be the correct way to set that up conditionally:

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <!--<![endif]-->

Comment: Never mind, it might be your media queries in main.css. Media queries are not supported in any version of IE prior to IE 9.

Comment: none of the media queries are currently being used. If you'll notice the viewport is set to 1260px to force mobile users to the "zoomed out view" - unfortunate requirements of the project at this time. Either way the media queries shouldn't effect anything related to the scrollbar or width of the site right now

Comment: Yeah, I'm note sure, if I find a PC with IE8 I might look at it again later tonight.

Comment: Do you by chance have an Overflow:hidden that might only be active on IE:8?